# Get result from mongo aggregation using pymongo 3.0

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using python to query a mongo collection and retrieve a value from it:

```
subquery = db.partsupp.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"r_name": region }},
        {"$group": {
            "_id" : 0,
            "minim": {"$min": "$supplycost"}
            }
        }
])
```

This query works just fine and it outputs:

```
[{'_id': 0, 'minim': 10}]
```

What I am trying to do now is to get the `minim` value from this aggregation.

Initially what I wanted was an 'if' to check if the query had any results, like this:

```py
if len(subselect['result']) > 0 :
    minim = subquery['result'][0]['minim']
else: 
    return subselect
```

But doing this only gets me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "query2.py", line 195, in <module>  
pprint( list(query2('Catalonia', 1, 1)) )  
File "query2.py", line 72, in query2

if len(subquery['result']) > 0 :  
TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object is not subscriptable
```

It looks like the result from the `subselect` query is not iterable or something like that, how can I solve this?

I am using Python 3.4.3 and pymongo 3.0.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pymongo 3.0.1 returns [aggregation results as cursor](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=aggregate#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate), which means you can't access the result with `subquery['result']`. To disable cursor and force pymongo to return a document with `{'result':{...}}` instead of a cursor, use this:

```
subquery = db.partsupp.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"r_name": region }},
        {"$group": {
            "_id" : 0,
            "minim": {"$min": "$supplycost"}
            }
        }
], useCursor=False)
```

From pymongo 4.0, useCursor is no  longer available, use list() to convert cursor to a list:

```
cursor = db.partsupp.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"r_name": region }},
        {"$group": {
            "_id" : 0,
            "minim": {"$min": "$supplycost"}
            }
        }
])
subquery['result'] = list(cursor)
```

Comment: It's supposed to work with any mongodb version > 2.6

Comment: i fetch same problem and i try above code but its give following error.pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', 'mytable'), ('pipeline', [{'$group': {'_id': '$name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}]), ('useCursor', False)]) on namespace mydb.$cmd failed: unrecognized field 'useCursor'

Answer (score 1):

Since useCursor is deprecated and will be removed in PyMongo 4.0, I suggest iterating over the results:

```
subquery = db.partsupp.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"r_name": region }},
        {"$group": {
            "_id" : 0,
            "minim": {"$min": "$supplycost"}
            }
        }
])
results = [doc for doc in subquery]
```